# Error 535 whilst trying to send email from Python and NTLM library

Tags: python, email, exchange-server

I'm trying to successfully authenticate against an Exchange SMTP gateway using Python.

I'm using the ntlm_auth module from https://github.com/jborean93/ntlm-auth and Python 3.5.2.

1. I can login to webmail using these credentials. I know they work.
2. I can send email using PowerShell, I know that works.

This is the code I am using. I've read the NTLM specifications and the server is not accepting the authenticated message. 5.7.3 is a generic error, is there a better way of handling this scenario?

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from ntlm_auth.ntlm import Ntlm
import socket
from smtplib import SMTPException, SMTPAuthenticationError

workstation = socket.gethostname().upper()

def ntlm_authenticate(smtp, domain, username, password):
    code, response = smtp.docmd("AUTH", "NTLM")
    ntlm_context = Ntlm(ntlm_compatibility=2)
    if code != 334:
        raise SMTPException("Server did not respond as expected to NTLM negotiate message")

    code, response = smtp.docmd(ntlm_context.create_negotiate_message(domain, workstation).decode())

    if code != 334:
        raise SMTPException("Server did not respond as expected to NTLM challenge message")

    ntlm_context.parse_challenge_message(response)

    code, response = smtp.docmd(ntlm_context.create_authenticate_message(username, password,
                                                                         domain, workstation).decode())
    if code != 235:
        raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, response)

EXCHANGE_PASSWORD = 'ThisIsReallyMyPassword!'

fromaddr = 'anthony.shaw@ourcompany.com'
toaddrs = 'my.colleague@ourcompany.com'
msg= 'hello world!'

print("Message length is", len(msg))

conn = SMTP('webmail.ourcompany.com')
conn.set_debuglevel(1)
conn.starttls()
conn.ehlo()
ntlm_authenticate(conn, 'DOMAINXXX', 'anthony.shaw', EXCHANGE_PASSWORD)
conn.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
conn.quit()
```

Here is a trace of the session, with various crypto words mangled for security

```
Message length is 12
send: 'ehlo Anthonys-MacBook-Pro-2.local\r\n'
reply: b'250-sdfsdf.sdfd.cloud Hello [121.123.184.192]\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 37748736\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-DSN\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250-AUTH NTLM\r\n'
reply: b'250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 XRDST\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'asd.sds.cloud Hello [121.123.184.192]\nSIZE 37748736\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nSTARTTLS\nX-ANONYMOUSTLS\nAUTH NTLM\nX-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM\n8BITMIME\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nXRDST'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 SMTP server ready'
send: 'ehlo Anthonys-MacBook-Pro-2.local\r\n'
reply: b'250-sdfdfs.dddd.cloud Hello [121.123.184.192]\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 37748736\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-DSN\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN\r\n'
reply: b'250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 XRDST\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: dd.bbb.cloud Hello [121.123.184.192]\nSIZE 37748736\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nAUTH NTLM LOGIN\nX-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM\n8BITMIME\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nXRDST'
send: 'AUTH NTLM\r\n'
reply: b'334 NTLM supported\r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: b'NTLM supported'
send: 'TlRMTVNTUAABAAsdfsdfsdfsdfBQAoAAAAHAAcAC0AAAAGAbEdAAAAD0lUQUFTQU5USE9OWVMtTUFDQk9PSy1QUk8tMi5MT0NBTA==\r\n'
reply: b'334 TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABwAHADgAAAA2gonilvWzl6ZwMogAAAAAAAAAALYAtgA/AAAABgLwIwAAAA9DU0ZNRERTAgAOAGMAcwBmAG0AZABkAHMAAQsdfdsdfsfRABEAFMARAAwADEARQAwADIABAAaAGMAcwBmAG0AZABkAHMALgBjAGsdfdsAAwA2AEEAVQAwADEARABEAFMARAAwADEARQAwADIALgBjAHMAZgBtAGQAZABzAC4AYwBsAG8AdQBkAAUAGgBjAHMAZgBtAGQAZABzAC4AYwBsAG8AdQBkAAcACAD5GqJRU3DSAQAAAAA=\r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: b'TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABwAHADgAAAA2gonilvWzl6ZwMogAAAAAAAAAALYAtgA/AAAABgLwIwAAAA9DU0ZNRERTAgAOAGMAcwBmAG0AZABkAHMAAQAaAEEAVQAwADEARABEAFMARAAwADEARQAwADIABAAaAGMAcwBmAG0AZABkAHMALgBjAGwAbwB1AGQAAwA2AEEAVQAwADEARABEAFMARAAwADEARQAwADIALgBjAHMAZgBtAGQAZABzAC4AYwBsAG8AdQBkAAUAGgBjAHMAZgBtAGQAZABzAC4AYwBsAG8AdQBkAAcACAD5GqJRU3DSAQAAAAA='
send: 'TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHUAAAfdfdfdfQAAAAUABQBIAAAADAAMAE0AAAAcABwAWQAAABAAEAClAAAANoKJ4gYBsR0AAAAPSVRBQVNhbnRob255LnNoYXdBTlRIT05ZUy1NQUNCT09LLVBSTy0yLkxPQ0FM8yeaKY0RjtEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD6wAaUOQF3QLY4klpKRYBYlkbYjyBNMJRLW0ZRQqzhDumAsyVC1uXg==\r\n'
reply: b'535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_users.py", line 38, in <module>
    ntlm_authenticate(conn, 'DOMAINXXX', 'anthony.shaw', EXCHANGE_PASSWORD)
  File "email_users.py", line 24, in ntlm_authenticate
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, response)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question, I noted that "It works in PowerShell". I ran WireShark on the Windows PC and ran the PowerShell commands again.

In the Wireshark session, I saw the same error "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful".
The PowerShell command (Send-MailMessage) ignores the error and continues to send the message (MAIL FROM, RCPT TO) and the message is delivered.

The issue here is that 5.7.3 can mean that an authenticated relay session cannot be established because this user does not have permissions to relay externally. However, you can run an anonymous relay session by ignoring the error and continuing to send the message.